# Redshift: Getting rank of a row, filtered by a condition

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Every time I add a row to a table, I want to know where it ranks in comparison with the table up to that point.  This is easily done with the RANK() window function.  However, I'm struggling to find a way to to discover where it ranks in comparison with the table up until that point **filtered by a value**.

As an example, I'm wanting to end up with this highly contrived table:

```
    date    |   name  | animal_bought | num_sloths_bought_before | num_camels_bought_before
------------+---------+---------------+--------------------------+--------------------------
 2014-09-01 | Vincent | sloth         | 0                        | 0
 2014-09-01 | Luis    | camel         | 0                        | 0
 2014-09-02 | Vincent | sloth         | 1                        | 0
 2014-09-02 | Luis    | camel         | 0                        | 1
 2014-09-02 | Kevin   | sloth         | 0                        | 0
 2014-09-03 | Vincent | camel         | 1                        | 0
 2014-09-04 | Deo     | camel         | 0                        | 0
 2014-09-04 | Vincent | sloth         | 2                        | 1
 2014-09-05 | Luis    | camel         | 0                        | 2
 2014-09-05 | Andrew  | sloth         | 0                        | 0
```

I was initially looking to see whether I could apply a filter to the window function (eg. `RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY name WHERE animal_bought = 'sloth' ORDER BY date ASC) AS num_sloths_bought_before`) but this isn't syntactically correct. I then tried adding a sub-query, as follows:

```
SELECT
  date,
  name,
  animal_bought,
  ( SELECT
      RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date ASC) - 1
    FROM this_table
    WHERE animal_bought = 'sloth'
  ) AS num_sloths_bought_before
FROM source_table
```

but Redshift threw this error:

```
ERROR:  This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported yet
```

I've also tried putting the window function in a case statement (throws the same error) and calculating the ranks in a join query (not been able to make it work).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm.  I don't think this query would do what you want anyway:

```
SELECT date, name, animal_bought,
       (SELECT RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date ASC) - 1
        FROM this_table
        WHERE animal_bought = 'sloth'
       ) AS num_sloths_bought_before
FROM source_table
```

For a few reasons:

- The use of `rank()` suggests that there is more than one row in `this_table` that matches `animal_bought`.  Otherwise, you could use an aggregation function.
- If there is only one row that matches the `where` clause, then the value is always 1, because the `where` clause is processed before the `rank()`.
- Your question only mentions one table but your query has two

Perhaps you just want `rank()` without a subquery?

```
SELECT date, name, animal_bought,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY name, animal ORDER BY date ASC) - 1 as NumberBoughtBefore
FROM source_table;
```

If you want it for both animals, then don't use `rank()`, use cumulative sum:

```
SELECT date, name, animal_bought,
       sum(case when animal = 'sloth' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by name order by date) as SlothsBefore,
       sum(case when animal = 'camel' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by name order by date) as CamelsBefore
FROM source_table;
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT date, name, animal_bought,
       (sum(case when animal = 'sloth' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by name order by date) -
        (case when animal = 'sloth' then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as SlothsBefore,
       (sum(case when animal = 'camel' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by name order by date) -
        (case when animal = 'camel' then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as CamelsBefore
FROM source_table;
```

Comment: Thanks, Gordon.  Unfortunately, that produces a table that contains the total number of times a name has bought an animal on each row, rather than the total number of times it happened **before** that row.  That is: every row for `Vincent` has a 3 in `sloths_bought` and a 1 in `camel_bought`, rather than increasing from row to row.

Comment: @Serenthia . . . Just subtract 1 or use a range/rows clause in the partition.

Comment: I'm afraid that produces the same result - the ````SUM()```` counts all the times the event has ever occurred, and then puts that same total on every row for that person.  I'm needing a different number on each row (as is produced by the ````RANK()```` function).  Thanks again for your input!

Comment: @Serenthia  . . . The `sum() . . . over` is *not* producing a cumulative sum?  The `order by` should be making it cumulative.

Comment: Sorry - I had to put this down for a while.  Returning, I've discovered that your solution DOES in fact work.  It's just missing the frame clause ````ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING````.  The reason it wasn't working before was because of an incorrect frame clause of mine.  Thanks so much for your input!

Comment: Is it possible to have two checks in the where clause of the nested query?   -- something like -- "SELECT date, name, animal_bought,
       (SELECT RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date ASC) - 1
        FROM this_table
        WHERE animal_bought = 'sloth' and columnB='test'
       ) AS num_sloths_bought_before
FROM source_table"

Comment: @Tisha . . . If you want to ask a question, then do so as a question rather than in a comment.